# Shift procedure execution contex

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I'm running a very simple proc in MySQL, something very similar to this:

```
insert into link_table ( primary_key_1, primary_key_2 )

select 
    table1.primary_key, 
    table2.primary_key

from
    table1
    inner join table_ref on table_ref.field_name1 = table1.field_name
    inner join table2    on table2.field_name = table_ref.field_name2
```

This string comparison join is taking way longer than I expected, about 1.5s per insert, at its running across ~8000 rows.

As far as I understand it, each procedure / query is executed within the context of a user.  That means if the user loses connection or power, then the query loses context and hence the transaction fails.

Is there a way to shift the execution context of the procedure to a "system" user or something similar?  This way I can go grab a coffee and watch a movie or something.

Comment: I think this question is more appropriate for dba.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

The question about "context" is more appropriate for dba.stackexchange.com.  However, you can probably make the query more efficient.  Here is the query:

```
insert into link_table( primary_key_1, primary_key_2 )
select table1.primary_key, table2.primary_key
from table1 inner join
     table_ref
     on table_ref.field_name1 = table1.field_name inner join
     table2
     on table2.field_name = table_ref.field_name2;
```

You should be able to speed this query with the following indexes:

```
table_ref(field_name1, field_name2)
table2(field_name, primary_key)
```

Improving the performance might solve your problem.